# What is relation between CentOS defaultly confiteor repos and vault (online repos)

Tags: centos, package, centos7, yum

I have some doubts about Yum repositories (CentOS case). My doubts are related to CentOS 7.2. Please consider my default content:

```
ls -al /etc/yum.repos.d
CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Sources.repo  CentOS-fasttrack.repo CentOS-CR.repo    CentOS-Media.repo
```

What is the relation between these repos (for example **Base** or **Sources**) and repos available on http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/ ?
    For example **os** or **updates** directory ? Are they equivalent ? I cannot find any information in the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

`CentOS-Base.repo` contains the most common and the most updated packages, and are repositories which can be left enabled (almost) all the times.

`CentOS-Sources.repo` contains instructions on how to reach the .src.rpm files, which are the files that are used to create the final .rpm files: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager#SRPM.

The address vault.centos.org is the official repository containing archived versions of the whole CentOS repository structure.
(It actually doesn't store much of its files, since if you try e.g. to download an old ISO it will tell you to get it from other mirrors, one in the US and a couple in Europe).

For more details, see the official CentOS FAQ: https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General
and in particular the wiki page related to repositories: https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories